# How to outsource upload function as service notde.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture, sails.js

I'm trying to write a piece of my upload code as a service, because I need that function overall in my software. My project use sails.js - here the doc for a [service](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/services/creating-a-service).

In a controller I got this code, which uploads a file and after success it calls the function saveTheCampaign() and saves the file information in the DB.

```
req.file('logo').upload({
         maxBytes: 10000000,
         saveAs: function (uploadFile, cb) {
         cb(null, Date.now() + uploadFile.filename);
         },
         dirname: sails.config.appPath + '/assets/images/campaign/'
         }, function (err, uploadedFiles) {
         if (err) {
         return res.json(500, err);
         }
         else if (uploadedFiles.length === 0) {
         // proceed without files
         res.json({ error: "No image found for upload!"})
         }
         else {
         //  Success: handle uploaded file
         var fileName = uploadedFiles[0].fd.split('\\');
         params["logo"] = fileName[fileName.length - 1];

         sails.controllers.campaign.saveTheCampaign(params, req, res);
         }
 });

 saveTheCampaign: function (params, req, res) { //...}
```

Now I wanted to write this snippet as a service. My service is called UploadService and has a function called upload(), [services](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/services/creating-a-service) can take two(2) arguments, option and a callback function. So I tried this to call the upload function of my service:

```
UploadService.upload(options, sails.controllers.campaign.saveTheCampaign(params, req, res));
```

The problem is, the params of the callback function (params, req, res) are not known at the time of the call, I get them AFTER the upload function is finished. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make this happen by using [Q Promise Library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). The snippet below is a working example for the same. You'll need to set value for `sails.config.appPath`.

**Routes.js**

```
'POST /upload' : 'CampaignController.upload'
```

**UploadService.js**

```
let q = require("q"); // https://github.com/kriskowal/q
module.exports = {
  upload: function(options) {
    let deferred = q.defer();
    options['req'].file(options['fileFieldName']).upload({
      maxBytes: 10,
      saveAs: function(uploadedFile, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + uploadedFile.filename);
      },
      dirname: sails.config.appPath + '/assets/images/'
    }, function(err, uploadedFiles) {
      if (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
      } else if (uploadedFiles.length === 0) {
        // proceed without files
        deferred.reject("No image found for upload!");
      } else {
        //  Success: handle uploaded file
        let params = [];
        var fileName = uploadedFiles[0].fd.split('\\');
        params["logo"] = fileName[fileName.length - 1];
        deferred.resolve(params)
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

**CampaignController.js**

```
module.exports = {
  upload: function(req, res) {
    let options = [];
    options['fileFieldName'] = 'logo';
    options['req'] = req;
    UploadService.upload(options)
      .then((params) => {
        sails.controllers.campaign.saveTheCampaign(params);
        res.send("Campaign Saved Successfully");
      })
      .catch((err) => res.send(err))
  },

  saveTheCampaign: function(params) {
    console.log(`campaign ${params['logo']} saved`);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, it worked now for me after some changes. what is the difference between the normal Promise and this Q library? https://jsfiddle.net/ah3322/396o81xb/